# Chemfig: \color doesn't work

Tags: color, chemfig, chemistry

Why `\color`doesn't work? I need to color the `-OH` oxydrilic function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2-[:-60,,3]C(-[:-120]H)=C(-[:-60]H)-[:60]H}
\arrow(.-1--){->[\chemfig{H_2O}][\chemfig{H^+}]}[,1.5]
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2-[:-0]C(-[:90]{\color{red}OH})(-[:-90]H)-C(-[:-90]H)(-[:90]H)(-[:0]H)}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the manual section 12.1 *How to write a colored atom* (p. 42 of the manual to v1.2e 2017-05-20)

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but: version 4 of `mhchem` was released about two years ago so `\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}` seems more appropriate (unless you have an outdated TeX distribution…)

Answer (score 4):

Using `\textcolor` seems to make it work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2-[:-60,,3]C(-[:-120]H)=C(-[:-60]H)-[:60]H}
\arrow(.-1--){->[\chemfig{H_2O}][\chemfig{H^+}]}[,1.5]
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2-[:-0]C(-[:90]{\textcolor{red}{OH}})(-[:-90]H)-C(-[:-90]H)(-[:90]H)(-[:0]H)}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Apparently, using `{\color{red}{OH}}` also makes it work, just by bracing the "OH".  Alternately, so does `{{\color{red}OH}}`, with the double brace.

However, as noted by the OP, it would be desirable to get just the oxygen linked to the bond, and so (after consulting the manual against my better judgment :^) I came up with this, in which I use a `|` to separate the atom specification, and apply color to each, respectively, as in `{\color{red}{O}|\color{red}{H}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2-[:-60,,3]C(-[:-120]H)=C(-[:-60]H)-[:60]H}
\arrow(.-1--){->[\chemfig{H_2O}][\chemfig{H^+}]}[,1.5]
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2-[:-0]C(-[:90]{\color{red}{O}|\color{red}{H}})(-[:-90]H)-C(-[:-90]H)(-[:90]H)(-[:0]H)}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This behaviour is actually documented: section 12.1 *How to write a colored atom* p. 42 of the manual to v1.2e 2017-05-20 :)

Comment: I noticed that adding the color effect, it changes the bind offset. How would I do if I wanted carbon directly bound to oxygen?

Comment: @SalvoMatteini I am not a user of the package to know the proper way, but this will, I think, give what you want: `{\textcolor{red}{O\rlap{H}}}`

Comment: @SalvoMatteini `-{\color{red}O}|{\color{red}H}` should work

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes using `\llap`/`\rlap` with `chemfig` should rarely if ever be necessary…

Comment: @clemens Don't tell me I have to read the manual!!?? :^)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I would never! ;)

Comment: @SalvoMatteini clemens tells me I don't need a `\rlap`, and indeed I don't if I resort to this longer syntax: `{\color{red}{O}|\color{red}{H}}`, using the vertical bar to separate the atoms, and applying color to each, respectively.